# use Google Maps API v3 on Unity 3D

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, unity-game-engine

I need to insert maps from Google Maps on a Unity 3D Application.

I think can be use API v3 for JavaScript but i don't know how begin.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [google static](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro?hl=en) image api in unity3d and you also need to register on google for getting **api key**. Or you can use [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3573) free asset store package but you have to purchase **uniWeb** as well. 
I use this Simple Code snippet for getting google image on a gameobject below:

```
       string url = "";
        /// <summary>
        /// Langitude/latitude of area. default Karachi is set
        /// </summary>
        public float lat =  24.917828f;

        public float lon = 67.097096f;
        LocationInfo li;
        /// <summary>
        /// Maps on Google Maps have an integer 'zoom level' which defines the resolution of the current view.
        /// Zoom levels between 0 (the lowest zoom level, in which the entire world can be seen on one map) and 
        /// 21+ (down to streets and individual buildings) are possible within the default roadmap view. 
        /// </summary>
        public int zoom = 14;
        /// <summary>
        /// not more then 640 * 640 
        /// </summary>
        public int mapWidth = 640;
        public int mapHeight = 640;

        public enum mapType { roadmap, satellite, hybrid, terrain };
        public mapType mapSelected;
        /// <summary>
        /// scale can be 1,2 for free plan and can also be 4 for paid
        /// </summary>
        public int scale;
 IEnumerator GetGoogleMap()
    {
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lon +
                "&zoom=" + zoom + "&size=" + mapWidth + "x" + mapHeight + "&scale=" + scale 
                +"&maptype=" + mapSelected +
                "&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=YourAPIKeyWillbeHere";
            loadingMap = true;
            WWW www = new WWW(url); 
            yield return www;
            loadingMap = false;
    //Assign downloaded map texture to any gameobject e.g., plane
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
 void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(GetGoogleMap());
    }
```

**Remembe**r Google not allowed Free access of greater then **640x640** Image.

Comment: Hi, I'm used this code and works, but markers don't shown. I had created a API Key por Browser, it's ok this?

Comment: because url doesn't contain marker option. Read API link which mention in answer.

Comment: or you can use this url (update it according to your requirments) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&
markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Thanks you! now I need to use tiles. :)

Comment: please share me  as u know about how to get tiles . i require it too

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/17266 this asset can help you for getting tiles. please check and let me know

Comment: If you are adding the map to a Canvas / UI element, you would replace the line: `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = www.texture;` with `gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = www.texture;` (in Unity 5) - where Raw Image is attached to an empty game object within the canvas. Also, make sure your script includes the `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top to be able to modify the UI